# Xamarin Forms download a json file with httpclient : ReadAsStringAsync or DownloadFileAsync?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I use a json file for populate listview in a Xamarin Forms Android/Ios app and like to download the json file on start.

Is it better to use ReadAsStringAsync or DownloadFileAsync?

DownloadFileAsync is not for binary only? nut maybe fastestthen read string and write it :)

Thanks

Comment: For JSON read it as string. Or read as bytes if serializer supports byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to directly save the data to disk as a file, use DownloadFileAsync() - it will be a simpler and faster solution than `ReadAsStringAsync()` because `DownloadFileAsync()` will use streams to write content in files, instead of first reading network data as a string and writing it to file stream with `StreamWriter`.

`String` is never good for performance. Even if you want to parse that JSON content downloaded from the network in code directly instead of saving on disk, you can read response with `ReadAsStreamAsync()` and you that stream to deserialize JSON object with `JsonSerializer`.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you want to download JSON content and deserialize directly to a model. For example:

```
private sealed class YourModel
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}

using (var req = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.example.com/api/endpoint"))
{
    req.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    using (var s = await req.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
    using (var jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        var obj = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<YourModel>();
    }
}
```

There are extensions you can use that make this simpler, for example, if you imported the `System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions` nuget package then you could do this:

```
using (var req = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.example.com/api/endpoint"))
{
    EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var obj = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<YourModel>();
}
```

If you don't want to use models, then typically JSON content would be downloaded as `string`.